# Monit will not start my node js app

Tags: troubleshooting, node.js, monit, upstart

I have a problem with Monit that I use for monitoring of my Node.js app. I just moved from a single core machine to a multi core one. On both of them I run Ubuntu 11.10. On the old one this was working. This script below uses a upstart script that I have configured according to this: http://howtonode.org/deploying-node-upstart-monit

```
check process nodejs with pidfile "/var/run/myapp.pid"
    start program = "/sbin/start myapp"
    stop program  = "/sbin/stop myapp"
    if failed port 80 protocol HTTP
        request /
        with timeout 10 seconds
        then restart
```

Now when I try to run it, such as: `monit -d 60 -c /etc/monit/monitrc` everything goes fine:

```
monit daemon at 1312 awakened
```

On the old machine that started myapp right away. On the new one it doesn't.

The mayer problem is that when my Node App crashes monit isn't helping me. I 
C